# Converting standard_conforming_strings from off to on when importing Postgres dump

Tags: postgresql, migration, import, postgresql-8.1

I've got a Postgres 8.1 instance which has `standard_conforming_strings` set to `off` (== handles slashes as escape characters). Recent Postgres versions have this setting `on` by default (for good reasons).

When importing a dump from 8.1 to 9.x, then I can set this setting to `off` in the 9.x DB but I don't want to, I'd prefer converting the dump into the proper format. This is a ~100GB dump.

How could I do that? Can I simply turn this setting 'on' in the 8.1 version? (Will that affect exporting existing data? Will/can that corrupt or modify existing data?)

What doesn't work: simply importing data produced by 8.1 to 9.x without setting standard_conforming_strings to `off` in the 9.x DB; the result is corrupted data.

Answer (score 3):

Testing with a 8.1 instance, it doesn't look that there is a problem. See these 3 different examples:

***Create data***

```
 SHOW standard_conforming_strings ;
 standard_conforming_strings 
 -----------------------------
  off

CREATE TABLE bla(t text);
INSERT INTO bla VALUES('abc''def');
INSERT INTO bla VALUES(E'abc\\def');
```

***1. Dump of 8.1 data with 8.1 pg_dump***

```
$ pg81/bin/pg_dump db
```

this produces (after removing the irrelevant stuff):

```
COPY bla (t) FROM stdin;
abc'def
abc\\def
\.
```

Here `standard_conforming_strings` does not matter because the COPY format is independant from it. When this COPY is executed, it will make no difference whether it's on or off.

***2. Dump of 8.1 data with 8.1 pg_dump with --inserts option***

```
$ pg81/bin/pg_dump --inserts db
```

So COPY is not used.
The dump now contains, for the interesting part:

```
INSERT INTO bla VALUES ('abc''def');
INSERT INTO bla VALUES (E'abc\\def');
```

Since the `E'...'` syntax is used, `standard_conforming_strings` is again irrelevant. These strings will be interpreted correctly,  whether the setting is on or off, by any version of postgres>=8.1

***3.Dump of 8.1 data with 9.1 pg_dump with --inserts option***

```
$ pg91/bin/pg_dump --inserts db
```

Now the dump happens to contain this, somewhere at the start

```
SET standard_conforming_strings = off;
```

and then in the data section:

```
INSERT INTO bla VALUES ('abc''def');
INSERT INTO bla VALUES ('abc\\def');
```

So again it's being taken care of automatically, albeit differently than with 8.1's pg_dump, but this dump is going to be reloadable directly in any version of postgres>=8.1, without tweaking anything.